# Why photoswipe.com does not build tiles with big images

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using the [Photoswipe plugin](https://photoswipe.com/). It only works with small thumbnails but I have big images already on my server it does not makes tiles correctly.

Here is working demo with small images: [Code sandbox with small images](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-3z1kub?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Here not working with big images: [Code sandbox with big images](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-adpqf1?file=src%2FApp.vue)

What is wrong with [my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-adpqf1?file=src%2FApp.vue)? I'm using big images, I don't have any small images. Is it possible with those big images?

```js
<template>
  <div :id="galleryID">
    <a
      v-for="(image, key) in imagesData"
      :key="key"
      :href="image.largeURL"
      :data-pswp-width="image.width"
      :data-pswp-height="image.height"
      target="_blank"
      rel="noreferrer"
    >
      <img :src="image.thumbnailURL" alt="" />
    </a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PhotoSwipeLightbox from 'photoswipe/lightbox';
import 'photoswipe/style.css';

export default {
  name: 'SimpleGallery',
  props: {
    galleryID: String,
    images: Array,
  },
  setup(props) {
    return {
      imagesData: props.images,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    if (!this.lightbox) {
      this.lightbox = new PhotoSwipeLightbox({
        gallery: '#' + this.$props.galleryID,
        children: 'a',
        pswpModule: () => import('photoswipe'),
      });
      this.lightbox.init();
    }
  },
  unmounted() {
    if (this.lightbox) {
      this.lightbox.destroy();
      this.lightbox = null;
    }
  },
  methods: {},
};
</script>
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: You have posted the link to the _same_ codesandbox in both instances.

Comment: @CBroe sorry i have updated it please check once. thanks in advance !